# How to select all?

Tags: angular, angular-material

As far as 'Multiple Selection' goes:

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

```
/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings = new FormControl();

  toppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
}
```

Is there a way to 'precheck' the boxes like 'Extra cheese', 'Pepperoni'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your toppings with array of values you want to be checked at start:

```
toppings = new FormControl(['Extra cheese', 'Pepperoni']);

toppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

toppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];

toppings = new FormControl(this.toppingList);